# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to create a unique identifier variable from the index for the cluster training data to merge with the cluster assignment variable

```
clus_train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

It is throwing an error saying that

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-d0d098349dbc> in <module>()
  1 # create a unique identifier variable from the index for the
  2 # cluster training data to merge with the cluster assignment variable
----> 3 clus_train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

C:\Users\3016205\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reset_index(self, level, drop, inplace, 
col_level, col_fill)
3053                 # to ndarray and maybe infer different dtype
3054                 level_values = _maybe_casted_values(lev, lab)
-> 3055                 if level is None or i in level:
3056                     new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
3057 

TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Can you please help with this. I am using Python 3.x

Comment: data matters.  This snippet does not reproduce your error.  Please add context `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]]); df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: What's your pandas version? From the error it seems it expects an iterable for the level argument. Did you try `clus_train.reset_index(level=[0])`?

Comment: `i in level` expects an object that supports containment; `level` is `0`, an integer that is not an iterable.

Comment: You've hit a bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/02484605e3e10553672154f90688be165030b398 seems applicable. Upgrade pandas.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nice, with the sleuthing. I was looking for that myself.

Comment: clus_train.reset_index(level=[0]) is working.

Answer (score 7):

You have hit a bug in Pandas; you are using `reset_index()` on a dataframe with a single-set index with a Pandas version somewhere between 0.19.2 and 0.20.1. This is [issue #16263](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16263):

> between v0.19.2 and v0.20.1, the behavior of `DataFrame.reset_index` changed.
>   With a single set index:
>
> - It does not attempt to keep the column (essentially making drop=True always on)
> - level=int no longer works (iterables work)

Upgrade Pandas to 0.20.2 or newer.

As the bug report notes, a temporary work-around would be to use `level=[0]`.

Comment: @VenkateshSubramaniam: do you have the same error still, with the same traceback and line numbers? Then you haven't updated the pandas library your Python code uses. If you have a *new* error, in a different location, then you had two different problems, this one being solved. That may be subject to a new question.

Comment: @VenkateshSubramaniam: however, *doesn't work* doesn't tell me anything about what happens instead, so I can't help you.

Comment: @VenkateshSubramaniam: note that you can check versions with `pd.show_versions()`, that'll help you make sure you've upgraded.

Answer (score -1):

You're passing in `level` as a variable with value of `0`. Then you're using the `in` keyword to see if `i` is `in` the `level` variable. The `in` keyword basically means "look in this list/set/string/what-have-you and see if this other variable is contained within it". Python tries to look inside your `level` variable and finds that it's an `int` and doesn't know what to do, because you can't look inside an `int`. It's just its own thing, not a container for other things.

Comment: The OP is using Pandas.reset_index() **as documented**. This is an error in the implementation of `reset_index()`, not anything the OP did wrong.